# PostgreSQL: Remove value from JSONB column

Tags: sql, postgresql

I need to remove some value from a jsonb type column.

The jsonb value

```
{"services": [59, 61], "locations": ["34"]}
```

This query is not working.

```
select jsonb_set(data, '{services}', (data->'services') - 59) from employees 
WHERE data @> '{"services":[59]}';
```

However, this works:

```
select jsonb_set(data, '{locations}', (data->'locations') - '34') from 
employees WHERE data @> '{"services":[59]}';
```

How can I remove `59` from `services` without key index and without single quotes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> (data->'services') - 59

Removes an item by index

**Example**

> ```
> /*
>  - 3 is the index to be deleted in a NUMERIC array
>
>  0  14
>  1  15
>  2  16
>  3  17   * to be deleted
>  4  18
>
> */
> select '[14, 15, 16, 17, 18]'::jsonb - 3
> ```
>
> ```
> | ?column?         |
> | :--------------- |
> | [14, 15, 16, 18] |
> ```

**An array of elements to text**

> ```
> CREATE TABLE employees  (
>   id serial primary key,
>   data jsonb
> );
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> insert into employees(data) values 
> ('{"services": [50, 57, 59, 61], "locations": ["34"]}'::jsonb),
> ('{"services": [19, 21], "locations": ["34"]}'::jsonb)
> ;
> ```
>
> ```
> 2 rows affected
> ```

> ```
> -- The link was used (https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/54283/how-to-turn-json-array-into-postgres-array)
>
> select 
>   employees.id,
>   jsonb_set(data, '{services}', ('[' || string_agg('"' || elem::text || '"' ,' ,') || ']')::jsonb - '59')
> from employees, json_array_elements((data->'services')::json) elem
> WHERE data @> '{"services":[59]}'
> group by employees.id
> ;
> ```
>
> ```
> id | jsonb_set                                            
> -: | :----------------------------------------------------
>  1 | {"services": ["50", "57", "61"], "locations": ["34"]}
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=1a012b34229fadfe959ddadcbc1ad9c3)*

Comment: Which one is faster to search for an element ? ["50", "57", "61"] OR [50, 57, 61] ?

Comment: Search in  ["50", "57", "61"] is faster,
there is no type conversion from number to string.